# How to understand the '0' argument value for a dict path and print its value in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

A void pointer is defined as:

```
typedef void* TRIEHANDLE;
```

Then here is a variable definition:

```
TRIEHANDLE m_dictHandle;
```

Then there is a function defunition:

```
int initTrieHandle(TRIEHANDLE &handle, const char *dicPath = 0);
```

The function is called in an initialization code:

```
initTrieHandle(m_dictHandle,0);
```

I  don't have access to  the source code of initTrieHandle's implementation, but the code is compiled and runs fine. I think this function loads a dictionary into a trie data stru cture, and I want to see what is the file path name of the dictionary. But why is the 2nd argument of it is '0'? How can I print out the dictPath in gdb?
When I tried to print out the value of m_dictHandle , it says:

```
Attempt to dereference a generic pointer.
```

What I really  want is to find out what is the  dictionary path, but I don't understand why it can be '0'? Maybe the real path name is embedded in the implementation of the function which is invisible to me?

Add more info below:

```
(gdb) disass initTrieHandle
Dump of assembler code for function initTrieHandle:
   0x000000000082fae0 <+0>: mov    %rbx,-0x10(%rsp)
   0x000000000082fae5 <+5>: mov    %rbp,-0x8(%rsp)
   0x000000000082faea <+10>:    sub    $0x28,%rsp
   0x000000000082faee <+14>:    test   %rsi,%rsi
   0x000000000082faf1 <+17>:    mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x000000000082faf4 <+20>:    mov    %rsi,%rbp
   0x000000000082faf7 <+23>:    je     0x82fb30 <initTrieHandle+80>
   0x000000000082faf9 <+25>:    mov    $0x4,%esi
   0x000000000082fafe <+30>:    mov    %rbp,%rdi
   0x000000000082fb01 <+33>:    callq  0x40b100 <access@plt>
   0x000000000082fb06 <+38>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x000000000082fb08 <+40>:    js     0x82fb30 <initTrieHandle+80>
   0x000000000082fb0a <+42>:    mov    %rbp,%rdi
   0x000000000082fb0d <+45>:    callq  0x8313a0 <trie_new_from_file>
   0x000000000082fb12 <+50>:    test   %rax,%rax
   0x000000000082fb15 <+53>:    je     0x82fb66 <initTrieHandle+134>
   0x000000000082fb17 <+55>:    mov    %rax,(%rbx)
   0x000000000082fb1a <+58>:    mov    0x20(%rsp),%rbp
   0x000000000082fb1f <+63>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000082fb21 <+65>:    mov    0x18(%rsp),%rbx
   0x000000000082fb26 <+70>:    add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x000000000082fb2a <+74>:    retq   
   0x000000000082fb2b <+75>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x000000000082fb30 <+80>:    callq  0x831670 <alpha_map_new>
   0x000000000082fb35 <+85>:    xor    %esi,%esi
   0x000000000082fb37 <+87>:    mov    %rax,%rbp
   0x000000000082fb3a <+90>:    mov    $0xff,%edx
   0x000000000082fb3f <+95>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000082fb42 <+98>:    callq  0x8316d0 <alpha_map_add_range>
   0x000000000082fb47 <+103>:   mov    %rbp,%rdi
   0x000000000082fb4a <+106>:   callq  0x8313f0 <trie_new>
   0x000000000082fb4f <+111>:   mov    %rbp,%rdi
   0x000000000082fb52 <+114>:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x000000000082fb57 <+119>:   callq  0x831690 <alpha_map_free>
   0x000000000082fb5c <+124>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x000000000082fb61 <+129>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0x000000000082fb64 <+132>:   jne    0x82fb17 <initTrieHandle+55>
   0x000000000082fb66 <+134>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000082fb6b <+139>:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rbx
   0x000000000082fb70 <+144>:   mov    0x20(%rsp),%rbp
   0x000000000082fb75 <+149>:   add    $0x28,%rsp
   0x000000000082fb79 <+153>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: The `0` here is equivalent to `nullptr` or `NULL`.  That is the value of `dicPath`.

Comment: If is is NULL, how can a dictionary be loaded? Or inside the function, the actual file path is provided?

Comment: You are now asking what the function does.  We can only guess.

Comment: This is other's code. I don't have the source code of the function. Is there a way to get the actual file based on disass info?

Comment: If the function was not compiled with debugging symbols, then gdb knows as much as you do. The details of what is in the memory to which a `void*` points are a black box.

Comment: `dicPath = 0` is the default argument. It's likely telling the library that it should use the default dictionary. There might be a function like `get_dictionary_name`, look at documentation or header file.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, but initTrieHandle(m_dictHandle,0) is a function call, not a definition. So it pass '0' as the 2nd argument.

Comment: The question is solely about C++, not C, so please do not spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Yes, I am guessing that the function `initTrieHandle` will look at the path, if path is zero, it chooses a default dictionary, or maybe it decides to work without a dictionary. If path is non-zero, it tries to load that file. All programming languages use this method, if they are to make some function parameters optional.

Comment: So if there is a default dictionary, it must be inside the initTrieHandle function, which isn't visible?

Comment: This question may need more focus.  There are currently 9 questions in flight here.

Comment: Or try `initTrieHandle(m_dictHandle, "fullpath/myfile.dat");` Because even if there is a file, and you find it, it may not be in plain text format, you can't do much with it.

Comment: I don't what the file is, so I can't do "fullpath/myfile.dat".

Comment: Have you tried [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)? If the function `initTrieHandle()` opens a file this should become visible in `strace`. FYI: [Strace cheat sheet](https://linux-audit.com/the-ultimate-strace-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood OPs actual problem, it's about to find out which file is opened by a function internally for which the source code is not available nor a sufficient doc.

I myself have never used [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) before nor have I had a need for this. Nevertheless, I had the feeling it could solve the problem of OP.

To cite from [The ultimate strace cheat sheet](https://linux-audit.com/the-ultimate-strace-cheat-sheet/):

> The strace utility is very powerful to learn what a new or running process is doing. Due to its diversity of monitoring options, the tool is less accessible at first. This strace cheat sheet helps with getting the best out of this tool.

To observe file activity, I found two options to use `strace`:

- `strace -e trace=file` *<executable>*
- `strace -e open` *<executable>*.

There is also the option to look for a specific file handle but I'm not sure how to know the resp. file handle beforehand.

To demonstrate this, I made a small MCVE:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

/* API for THE SECRET FUNCTION
 * lacking sufficient doc.
 */
void openSomething(const char *filePath = nullptr);

/* THE SECRET FUNCTION
 * which might be provided by a 3rd party lib.
 * without source code and sufficient doc.
 */
void openSomething(const char *filePath)
{
  if (!filePath) filePath = "main.cpp";
  std::cout << filePath << ":\n";
  std::fstream file(filePath);
  for (std::string buffer; std::getline(file, buffer);) {
    std::cout << "| " << buffer << '\n';
  }
}

// the appl. where THE SECRET FUNCTION is used
int main()
{
  openSomething();
}
```

Compiled and executed with `strace`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && strace -e open ./a.out
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("main.cpp", O_RDWR)                = 3
main.cpp:
| #include <fstream>
| #include <iostream>
| 
| /* API for THE SECRET FUNCTION
|  * lacking sufficient doc.
|  */
| void openSomething(const char *filePath = nullptr);
| 
| /* THE SECRET FUNCTION
|  * which might be provided by a 3rd party lib.
|  * without source code and sufficient doc.
|  */
| void openSomething(const char *filePath)
| {
|   if (!filePath) filePath = "main.cpp";
|   std::cout << filePath << ":\n";
|   std::fstream file(filePath);
|   for (std::string buffer; std::getline(file, buffer);) {
|     std::cout << "| " << buffer << '\n';
|   }
| }
| 
| // the appl. where THE SECRET FUNCTION is used
| int main()
| {
|   openSomething();
| }
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

[**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/182967e2f5230c58)

Thereby, the relevant line is this:

```
open("main.cpp", O_RDWR)                = 3
```

which obviously appears just before the console output of my `/* SECRET FUNCTION */ openSomething()`.

---

I must admit the fact that `strace` can be demonstrated in coliru was the essential motivation to write this answer.

Comment: My Makefile was automatically generated by a CMake file. So do I need to modify my cmake file to include strace into it?

Comment: @marlon No. `strace` is a tool you call with your built executable (in Linux). You are working on Linux? (The fact that you exposed a `gdb` dump let me assume this.)